# Teamcity, Angular 2 -- my agent has unmet requirement: node.js.nvm exists. But node.js is there

Tags: angularjs, node.js, teamcity

I've installed Teamcity on my development machine (just playing at home) -- works like a charm. Changed website to be angular2 and it runs beautifully in my dev folder.
However, when I check in, and use the Teamcity 'node.js build runner' plugin, I now have 'unmet requirement' on the agent (local on same machine again).

How do I make it clear for the agant that node.js does indeed exist?

Furthermore, tips on deploying Angular2 apps through Teamcity-Octopus is welcome ;)

Thanks!

teamcity-agent.log below -- Node NVM installer runner not available. But it's already installed?

[2017-01-13 16:32:05,464]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Build Agent version: 42538, plugins signature: 42538-md5-9fc715f8b6575b8a3e87e1c00ea52cac 
[2017-01-13 16:32:05,858]   INFO - javaDowser.JavaDowserAgentImpl - JavaDowser: Found 2 java installations:
    1.7/64 (1.7.0_79) at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 (JDK) [200]
    1.8/32 (1.8.0_111) at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_111 (JRE) [300] 
[2017-01-13 16:32:05,859]   INFO - onfig.BuildAgentSystemInfoImpl - Node NVM installer runner is not available: Windows is not supported 
[2017-01-13 16:32:05,883]   INFO - .processes.ProcessExecutorImpl - Starting process: Execution(program=cmd.exe, arguments=[/c, node, --version]) 
[2017-01-13 16:32:05,944]   INFO - s.node.agent.NodeToolsDetector - node 7.4.0 was detected 
[2017-01-13 16:32:05,945]   INFO - .processes.ProcessExecutorImpl - Starting process: Execution(program=cmd.exe, arguments=[/c, npm, --version]) 
[2017-01-13 16:32:06,769]   INFO - s.node.agent.NodeToolsDetector - npm 4.0.5 was detected 
[2017-01-13 16:32:06,769]   INFO - .processes.ProcessExecutorImpl - Starting process: Execution(program=cmd.exe, arguments=[/c, grunt, --version]) 
[2017-01-13 16:32:06,803]   INFO - s.node.agent.NodeToolsDetector - grunt was not found or failed, exitcode: 1 
[2017-01-13 16:32:06,803]   INFO - s.node.agent.NodeToolsDetector - StdOut:
[2017-01-13 16:32:06,803]   INFO - s.node.agent.NodeToolsDetector - StdErr: 'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. 
[2017-01-13 16:32:06,803]   INFO - .processes.ProcessExecutorImpl - Starting process: Execution(program=cmd.exe, arguments=[/c, gulp, --version]) 
[2017-01-13 16:32:06,837]   INFO - s.node.agent.NodeToolsDetector - gulp was not found or failed, exitcode: 1 
[2017-01-13 16:32:06,837]   INFO - s.node.agent.NodeToolsDetector - StdOut:
[2017-01-13 16:32:06,837]   INFO - s.node.agent.NodeToolsDetector - StdErr: 'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. 
[2017-01-13 16:32:06,848]   INFO - ggers.vcs.mercurial.HgDetector - Cannot detect installed mercurial

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the agent properties page to see if node is there, if you've only recently installed it, then you'll have to restart the build agent, for it to pick it up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Node.js jonnyzzz.node plugin](http://teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt434) then add new build step to your build configuration and set it's runner as **Node.js NVM Installer**. Remember to specify required NodeJS version number in **Node.js version** input field. Make this build step as first build step of current configuration.